How to get the user's identity in API Gateway Private Api i.e. get identity using `x-api-key` token?
Anyone knows how to get the user's identity who made request to API (x-api-key) in lambda? Like we can extract from JWT token if authorizer is cognito
It's AWS API Gateway with Private enabled i.e. I'm passing a x-api-key token instead of JWT
